# Child window full-size in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, childwindow

I need to open a child window full-size in Chrome browser, the following code works fine in Firefox 16.0.2 and IE 9, but not in Google Chrome 22 . What am I missing?

```
window.open(href,"_blank","scrollbars=1,fullscreen=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fullscreen` option is supported by IE only ; you are "lucky", FF seems to accept it now, but Google Chrome doesn't support this feature...

You only can force width and height on your popup

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Thank you for quick response, @Doubidou .It seems like Chrome does not support
`height=screen.availHeight,width=screen.availWidth` either...

Comment: You can fix that : `window.open('http://www.google.fr','_blank','height='+screen.height+', width='+screen.width);`

Comment: @Doubidou screen.height and screen.width also not working in Chrome browser. Is there any other solution.